# How to GET attribute from class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a table called `USER` in my database. This table has an associated API in my C# program.

I have a variable that I'm populating with a `USER.ID` value. When I populate the field, I want to use my `GET` API to return the `USER.First_Name` and `USER.Last_Name` fields to set the value of a literal on my page.

Here's the code that I've tried, but I don't think that I'm on the right track (every time I try and get the attributes from my `user` variable, it tells me that I'm returning the wrong type/can't explicitly convert the value from HTTPActionGet to type `USER` or something like that.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:#####/api/");
            var user = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "user?=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestUserID"]);
            user u = new user();
            u = user;
            MyLiteral.Text = u.First_Name
            MyLiteral2.Text = u.Last_Name

        }

    }
```

I'm sure that this is probably very simple to do, but my Google-fu has failed me.

Comment: `GetAsync` returns an `HttpResponseMessage` which is more than just your user data. I can only assume, but you probably need to read the Content of `user` as a json string and deserialize it. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: what is the result of ` var user = client.GetAsync`?

Comment: what does your user object look like?  Does it match the json returned from the service call?  If so, deserialize directly into the object using json.net. you also probably want to use GetStringAsync

Comment: Your line `client.GetAsync()` needs to be awaited or have `client.GetAsync().Result` (on top of the other comments)

Comment: Be careful with terminology. `Attribute` means something entirely different than what you're referring to, which is a `Property`.

Comment: @Saif like the guy ahead of you said, it's returning an HttpResponseMessage (which I'm too dense to figure out how to work with).

Comment: Just parse the result from the HttpResponseMessage in json object

Comment: serialize   `user` instance to json first `var jsonUser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);`

Comment: @Saif that'd be going backwards. We need to deserialize the response content (read as a string) into type `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have expected to see some code similar to this :

```
 var response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "user?=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestUserID"]).Result;

 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
 {
     var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     user u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<user>(responseString);
}
```

Not that `JsonConvert` is from a NuGet package titled `Newtonsoft.Json`

We needed the `.Result` on the end of methods suffixed with `Async` because your method does not support asynchronous operations, so we cannot `await` them.

Comment: This gave me an error on the last line that said `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'`

Comment: What does `responseString` look like?

Comment: I suspect that the URL needs to be fixed and use `"?user="` instead.

Comment: @phroureo That means you are getting back xml or html. You are probably experiencing an error that you will need to correct. Look at the status code of the response and also debug into your API.

Comment: You're right, and I'm dumb! It was an issue with my API. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The `GetAsync` method returns a `Task`. Please [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.118).aspx) for more details.

What you need to do is await the method call so that you get back an object of type `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
var user = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "user?=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestUserID"]);
```

Alternatively, you can invoke the `Result` property of the `Task` returned to cause the method call to block and do the same:

```
var user = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "user?=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestUserID"]).Result;
```

You can then deserialize the contents of the response using [an extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true):

```
var u = user.Content.ReadAsAsync<user>();
```

This of course works provided your `User` type is serializable.

The `ReadAsAsync<>`extension method also supports an overload where you can specify a Media Type formatter if you are using custom serialization.

Comment: Whenever I try to use `await client.GetAsync` it gives me lots of red squigglies and an error that says `'HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of 'HttpResponseMessage' could be found`

Comment: You cannot use `await` because your method does not have the `async` signature

Comment: As @MarkC. mentioned, you cannot await so simply go the `Result` route.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried logging out the type that is being returned, as you are using the var keyword so the type is indeterminate as we see it.

Console.WriteLine(user.GetType())  or Trace.WriteLine or Debug.WriteLine to see the type of the user object being returned.

Once you see the type being returned that should clarify the fields which you are able to see and use.

Then you should be able to see if you're getting any data or not.

Final point - is that user?= syntactically correct on this line

var user = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "user?=" ...

Thank you

Phil

Comment: This is not an aswer